# Can I install on my PC an Arch Linux installed in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, virtualbox

I was wondering if I can install Arch Linux in VirtualBox, installing there all the apps I will use, and then make an ISO to install on my PC (I mean, as host and not as guest).

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: take a look on this post:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/32499/migrate-from-a-virtual-machine-vm-to-a-physical-system
Still I do not recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Making a bootable ISO (live CD/DVD) is a different process from installing that distribution in a VirtualMachine (VM).

If your host is non-arch (Windows, other Linux distribution), then first installing Arch in a VM and then using that VM to modify an existing live CD/DVD is a good way to work, as you can use the  tools from the arch in VM to update the unpacked and mounted elements from the Live CD/DVD image using `chroot` (i.e. mounted in the VM).

Make sure you have enough disc-space for the VM for at least one unpacked Live CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great ArchWiki article for this:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO

If you have a running linux system (preferrably arch) you can follow this guide straight, because of the use of chroot.

On Windows I would recommend booting the Arch-Live-CD, and work from there. You might need 2 copys of the Live-CD, one for booting in VM and one for editing. But I'm not sure.